# Why did Minho risk his life to save Alby?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

Early in the film, we see Alby leading the others in banishing - and thus condemning to death - someone who has been "stung". There seems to be no hope of a cure.

Yet when Alby is stung Minho risks being shut into the maze in order to carry him unconscious back to the Glade. Does he think he can somehow save him?

Comment: Maybe it was portrayed differently in the books? That does seem illogical.

Comment: Relevant reading: http://mazerunner.wikia.com/wiki/The_Maze_Runner_book_to_film_differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much known about either the Changing or The Banishment, as the events in both the book and movie happen near the end of the Maze events. Every rule was created by the Gladers long before Thomas shows up, so there is much unknown. What we can see though, is that the Changing doesn't effect everyone the same. Only four people are seen going through it, Ben, Alby, Thomas and Gally. We only see Ben being vanished, and he's pretty manic when it happens. Alby and Thomas both get stung, take the Grief Serum, and then are okay. Gally almost acts like Ben did.

Keep in mind, in the books, the Grief Serum already exists, so its always administered if the stung person is found in time. And Book Gally went through the Changing before Thomas even arrives.

This leads to the main question, why would Minho attempt to save Alby when Ben was Banished after being stung? **Aside from having to match the book version where this is a major event**, the Banishment of Ben seems to happen due to a separate reason. In the book, Minho's main reasoning is that there is a cure for being stung, so leaving Alby, their leader, in the Maze would be the same as killing him. There's a chance to save him. Ben, instead, was banished not because he was stung, but because **he attempted to kill Thomas**. Hurting another Glader is one of the worst things you can do, and the Rules required he be removed. I believe it had to do with Ben not being given the Serum in time, and that leaves him crazy and dangerous. The Gladers had no choice.

In the Movie Alby, unlike Ben, when stung, spends a week or so sick. If we consider that not everybody stung reacts the same as Ben, then the movie answer would simply be the same as the book. Ben was banished because he became a dangerous lunatic after the Changing, not because he was stung. While one happened because of the other, the end result is the same, only the Dangerous ones get Banished. So Minho, knowing this, would attempt to save Alby, because it was not guaranteed that he would become dangerous.

Comment: Aha, I wondered if the book was different. It makes much more sense if a serum already exists, so that some people have a chance to survive and others not. You couldn't simply have some people recovering naturally, or the later use of the serum would be less dramatic, and require waiting for Alby to reach some specific point of no return in order to risk it.

Comment: Not just that, but since seeing Scorch Trials, I'm almost positive that the Grief Serum is the kill zone enzyme, and the Griever sting is the Flare, so the Changing turns them into Cranks. @imsop

Comment: The book is obviously different form the movie, I saw for myself, all the books are different from the move in the maze runner series

Answer (score 0):

Minho is the Keeper of the Runners. He is one of the senior boys in the Glade, and for good reason. He is level-headed, brave, intelligent and not willing to give up.

He knew that to get out of the glades, he needs each and every soul. And being one of the senior boys, it's his responsibility to save them.

Although he didn't know that there was any hope for the cure, but his leadership quality to lead from the front, his form of responsibility towards each and everyone who has faith over him gave the strength to risk his life and bring him back from the maze.